# Merge sort does not split the right side of the list

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

Like the title states, my merge sort only splits the left side. Everything else works fine, including my merge function. I can't figure out why. I would really appreciate the help. In a list that includes: 7, 4, 10, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7, 11, 5 it outputs 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 10, 11, 5

EDIT: added the rest of my class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class linkedList
{
private:
    class node
    {
    public:
        int data;
        node * next;
        node * prev;


    node(int x)
    {
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
        prev = NULL;
    }
};

node * head;
node * tail;

node * split()
{
    node * finger = head;
    node * fast = head->next;
    while (fast != NULL)
    {
        fast = fast->next;
        if (fast != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next;
            finger = finger->next;
        }
    }
    tail = finger->next;
    node * splitB = tail;
    splitB->prev = NULL;
    finger->next = NULL;
    return splitB;
}

node * merge(node * a, node * b)
{
    linkedList m;

    while(a != NULL || b != NULL)
    {
        if(b == NULL)
        {
            if(m.head != NULL)
            {
                a->prev = m.tail;
                m.tail->next = a;
                m.tail = a;

            }
            else
            {
                m.head = a;
                m.tail = m.head;
            }
            a = a->next;
        }
        else if(a == NULL)
        {
            if(m.head != NULL)
            {               
                b->prev = m.tail;
                m.tail->next = b;
                m.tail = b;
            }
            else
            {
                m.head = b;
                m.tail = m.head;
            }
            b = b->next;
        }
        else if (a->data < b->data)
        {
            if(m.head == NULL)
            {
                m.head = a;
                m.tail = m.head;
            }
            else
            {
                a->prev = m.tail;
                m.tail->next = a;
                m.tail = a;
            }
            a = a->next;
        }
        else
        {
            if(m.head == NULL)
            {
                m.head = b;
                m.tail = m.head;
            }
            else
            {
                b->prev = m.tail;
                m.tail->next = b;
                m.tail = b;
            }
            b = b->next;
        }
    }
    return m.head;
}

node* mergeSort(node * a)
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        node * b = split();

        node* right = mergeSort(a);
        node* left = mergeSort(b);

        return merge(right, left);
    }
}



public:
    linkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }


void push_back(int x)
{
    node * baby = new node(x);

    if( head == NULL )
    {
        head=baby;
        tail=baby;
    }
    else
    {
        baby->prev = tail;
        tail->next = baby;
        tail = baby;
    }
}

void mergeSort()
{
    head = mergeSort(head);
}

bool empty()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int pop()
{
    int popMe = head->data;
    node * deleteMe = head;
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        delete deleteMe;
        return popMe;
    }
    else
    {
        head = head->next;
        head->prev = NULL;
        delete deleteMe;
        return popMe;
    }
}
//test
void display()
{
    node * finger = head;
    while(finger!=NULL)
    {
        cout << finger->data << endl;
        finger = finger->next;
    }
}

};
```

Comment: Which anomalies did you observe, when stepping through your code line by line using a debugger? Also provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: The `split()` function modifies a `tail` variable, but does not declare it. Where is the variable defined? Is it possibly global? Did you consider results of re-assigning values to global `tail` in recursive calls to `mergeSort()`?

Comment: The `mergeSort()` receives an `a` pointer to the list to be sorted. However the first decision made in the function **does not depend** on `a` at all! It is based on some external variable `head`, which needn't have anything to do with `a`...

Comment: I observed that the right or `b` variable in `mergeSort` does not get split, and only the `a` variable does, so once it tries to merge the left side with an unsplit right side. I also tried your suggestion, but now I get a break error message stating: "`Unhandled exception at 0x01123447 in code.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000008.`" and then points to `splitB->prev = NULL;` although I did change the line above it to `node * splitB = finger->next;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the merge sort you are going to have to break up the list. For example always splitting on head and tail is pointless. It would always be splitting on the whole list, not the increasingly smaller portions of the list. So your split would have to look something like this:

```
void split(node *& a, node *& b)
{
    node * finger = a;
    node * fast = a->next;
    while (fast != NULL)
    {
        fast = fast->next;
        if (fast != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next;
            finger = finger->next;
        }
    }
    b = finger->next;
    b->prev->next = NULL;
    b->prev = NULL; 
}
```

I recommend changing the variable names `fast` and `finger` to something more descriptive.

Merge and mergeSort will require similar modification.

Edited the post to do things the C++ way. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you don't mind explaining, why do you put two asterisks? What does that mean? What's the difference between `a->next;` and `(*a)->next;`

Comment: * is a pointer. ** is a pointer to a pointer. This lets you pass a pointer into a function, modify it, and get the result in the calling function. My using it is me falling back into old C habits. I should have used `node * & a` and used a reference to a pointer. Does the same thing in this case and is a bit safer to use. I'll update the answer.

Comment: `a->next;` says get me the value of the the class/structure member `next` of the variable that is pointed to by pointer `a`. `(*a)->next` is better explained in pieces. `*a` means get me the value at which `a` points. This is called dereferencing the pointer.  `(*a)` is just `*a` inside braces to make sure `*a` happens before `->next` just like you would put brackets around `2+3` if if you wanted `(2+3)*4` to equal 20 instead of 14. So `(*a)->next` means get me the value of `next` at the variable pointed at by the variable pointed at by `a`. Yuck. See why the C++ way is generally better?

Answer (score 0):

STOP USING GLOBAL VARIABLES!
Remove ALL variables declarations which appear before your functions.
Rely solely on data that were passed to the functions as their parameters.

**EDIT**

Here is (possibly minimal) modification of your original code, which does not use extern variables (except the parameterless `mergeSort()`, which is supposed to be the only public method, if you implement the code in some `sortableList` class).
The code also doesn't use `last` pointer nor `prev` links as they are not needed in `mergeSort` and can be easily reconstructed after sorting (easily means here 'in O(n) time' with a single pass along the sorted list).

```
// split the list and return a pointer to a second half
node * split(node * fast)
{
    // assert(fast != NULL)

    node * finger = fast;
    fast = fast->next;

    while (fast != NULL)
    {
        fast = fast->next;
        if (fast != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next;
            finger = finger->next;
        }
    }

    node * splitB = finger->next;
    finger->next = NULL;
    return splitB;
}

// sort the (sub)list and return its new head
node* mergeSort(node * a)
{
    // assert(a != NULL)    // list not empty

    node * b = split(a);    // take second half

    if (b != NULL)
    {
        a = mergeSort(a);
        b = mergeSort(b);

        a = merge(a, b);
    }
    return a;
}

void mergeSort()
{
    if (head != NULL)       // make sure list isn't empty
        head = mergeSort(head);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Your `merge` routine seems too long and overcomplicated. See the shorter version below. Isn't it more redable?

```
node * merge(node * a, node * b)
{
    // assert(a != NULL)
    // assert(b != NULL)

    node * head, * tail;

    if (a->data <= b->data)
        head = a, a = a->next;
    else
        head = b, b = b->next;
    tail = head;

    while (a != NULL && b != NULL)
    {
        if (a->data <= b->data)
            tail->next = a, a = a->next;
        else
            tail->next = b, b = b->next;
        tail = tail->next;
    }

    if (a != NULL)
        tail->next = a;
    else
        tail->next = b;

    return head;
}
```

You might also get rid of the first `if`, if you create a temporary `node` variable (but that is sometimes not allowed, say if `node` class is too complicated or its construction would cause some unwanted side effects):

```
node * merge(node * a, node * b)
{
    // assert(a != NULL)
    // assert(b != NULL)

    node head, * tail = &head;

    while (a != NULL && b != NULL)
    {
        if (a->data <= b->data)
            tail = tail->next = a, a = a->next;
        else
            tail = tail->next = b, b = b->next;
    }

    tail->next = a ? a : b;

    return head->next;
}
```

And this is how to restore `prev` links once the forward-linked list is sorted:

```
void restoreBacklinks()
{
    node * prev = NULL;

    for (node * p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        p->prev = prev;
        prev = p;
    }

    tail = prev;
}

void mergeSort()
{
    if (head != NULL)       // make sure list isn't empty
    {
        head = mergeSort(head);
        restoreBacklinks();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my post. It wasn't global. It was within my class definition.

Comment: You gave no indication about any *class*, the code looked like C. Anyway those variables were external to the functions presented and should not be used that way — `mergeSort()` calls itself recursively and executes `split()`, each `mergeSort()` and each `split()` deals with a different part of the list, which should be reflected by appropriate changes of `head`; however, none of them sets `head`, although both use it.

Comment: @RomanLopez See the code I added. (You might not get a notification on the previous comment, I suppose, so I repeat it with an appropriate 'at' pointer now.)